Issue Reading JSON from S3 with DuckDB: Datetime Parsing Error
I’m running into an issue when trying to read multiple JSON files from S3 using DuckDB, and I’d love some guidance.
Here’s the context:
I'm working with JSON files stored in S3. Each file has the following format:
{
   "metadata": "somestring",
   "value": [
        {"ID": 1, "SomeDate": "SomeDateStringOrNull"}
   ]
}

Note that each value array always contains a single item.
I am able to read a single file without any issues like this: SELECT * FROM read_json('s3://path/to/file.json');
However, when I try to read all files from the directory using:
WITH raw_data AS (
    SELECT * FROM read_json('s3://path/to/data/*.json')
),
json_data AS (
    SELECT json_extract(raw_data, '$.value') AS j
    FROM raw_data
)
SELECT j[0].ID, j[0].SomeDate
FROM json_data;

I get the following error:
Invalid Input Error: Json transform error in file <the file> could not parse string '2024-10-24T18:00:00.1234567Z' according to format specifier "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
2024-10-24T18:00:00.1234567Z
                    ^
Error: Literal does not match, expected Z

It seems like DuckDB is trying to infer the type of SomeDate and can't transform everything correctly due to the different date formats (specifically the precision beyond microseconds and the literal Z). Some example value for this field are:
null, 2024-10-24T18:00:00Z, and 2024-10-24T18:00:00.1234567Z
I tried exploring read_json.columns to specify the schema explicitly, but I haven’t had much success there either.
I’d really appreciate any advice on how to:

Prevent this type coercion during the read_json step.
Handle these datetime strings more gracefully to avoid parsing issues across multiple files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much for your time and assistance!
